# Paypal Merchant Account API Access

Tags: paypal

Everything I've seen in documentation and on the forums are all about processing payments. My client has a merchant account. The payments process is all working just fine. I need to access (via API) their account and retrieve a list of their payments (showing amount paid, fees, and remaining amount). I'm more than happy to read the manual...would somebody point me in the right direction as to which API I need to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of [TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) and [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) will get that done for you.

If you're working with PHP my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/) will make those calls very simple for you.